# How to solve the Nominatim problem

Tags: python, nominatim, geopy, openweathermap-api

I have a mini project about "Weather App", i use Nominatim to get location but it seems like not working.

Here is the code

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from tkinter import ttk,messagebox
from timezonefinder import TimezoneFinder
from datetime import *
import requests
import pytz
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.title("Weather App")
root.geometry("900x500+300+200")
root.configure(bg = "#57adff")
root.resizable(False, False)



#get weather

def getWeather():
    city = textfield.get()
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent = "geoapiExercises")
    location= geolocator.geocode(city, timeout = None)
    obj = TimezoneFinder()

    result = obj.timezone_at(lng = location.longitude, lat = location.latitude)

    timezone.config(text=result)
    long_lat.config(text = f"{round(location.latitude,4)}°N, {round(location.longitude,4)}°E")

    home = pytz.timezone(result)
    local_time = datetime.now(home)
    current_time = local_time.strftime("%I:%M %p")
    clock.config(text = current_time)
```

and the problem

```
        Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\84985\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\geopy\geocoders\base.py", line 368, in _call_geocoder
    result = self.adapter.get_json(url, timeout=timeout, headers=req_headers)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\84985\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\geopy\adapters.py", line 472, in get_json
    resp = self._request(url, timeout=timeout, headers=headers)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\84985\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\geopy\adapters.py", line 500, in _request
    raise AdapterHTTPError(
geopy.adapters.AdapterHTTPError: Non-successful status code 403

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\84985\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "v:\PYTHON\Python Weather Project\weather.py", line 24, in getWeather
    location= geolocator.geocode(city, timeout = None)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\84985\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\geopy\geocoders\nominatim.py", line 297, in geocode
    return self._call_geocoder(url, callback, timeout=timeout)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\84985\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\geopy\geocoders\base.py", line 388, in _call_geocoder
    res = self._adapter_error_handler(error)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\84985\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\geopy\geocoders\base.py", line 411, in _adapter_error_handler
    raise exc_cls(str(error)) from error
geopy.exc.GeocoderInsufficientPrivileges: Non-successful status code 403
```

Comment: Please paste the error message and the code here rather adding a screenshot.

Comment: okay, i've just fixed it

Comment: Looks like you have not correctly authenticated so the server returned a 403 response

Comment: you probably need to create a `user_agent`; see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/293615/user-agent-argument-in-nominatim-in-geopy

Comment: thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use: `geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent = "geoapiExercises")`

Replace with this: `geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent = "abcd")`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).